# How can I count the number of vectors different from zero vector?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 2016 different points $A_1, \ldots, A_{2016}$. I want to count the number of vectors different from zero vector with the vertices from the points $A_1, \ldots, A_{2016}$. Forexample, vector $\overrightarrow{A_1A_2}$.

I tried. There are 2016 ways to choose the first point and 2015 ways to choose the second point. Therefore, we have $2016 \cdot 2015$ vectors.

Comment: Note that there may be vectors that are equal even though their end points are different. For instance, if your points form a square.

Comment: @Arthur: I guess we caan suppose the points are ‘in general position’.

Comment: that's a really big guess imho

Comment: With $n$ points, the maximum possible number of non-zero vectors is $n(n-1)$. But there may be duplicates.

Comment: @TonyK How about duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just looking for the number of ways to order 2016 elements, so that's 2016!, continuing all the way down the path you started with 2016*2015*2014*2013*....*3*2*1.
The result is [this large number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2016!), about 2.33 * 10^5788.

[Click here for an introduction to the factorial operator (!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

*Note: This answer was posted on [this version of the question post](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1905338/1), which seemed to seek the number of possible 2016-element vectors where each element was pulled from a set of 2016 possibilities without replacement.  The question was edited to invalidate this answer.*

Comment: That is not how I understood the question.

Comment: @TonyK the question was changed to invalidate the answer.  I've just added a note to that effect in with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the points are different then any pair of points $A_i$ and $A_j$ with $i\neq j$ will give you two non-zero vectors $\vec{A_iA_j}$ and $\vec{A_jA_i}$. Therefore your question is transformed to another one: how many pairs can be built up from the set of $2016$ elements. This is a standard question from combinatorics and the answer is $2016\choose2$ which is equal to $\dfrac{2016\cdot2015}{2}$. Therefore, there are $2016\cdot 2015$ vectors in total.

Comment: No, that's wrong, because if $A_i \ne A_j$, then $\vec{A_iA_j} \ne \vec{A_jA_i}$.

Comment: Thanks @TonyK. Sorry for the silly mistake. Edited the answer.